# How-to merge two lists returned by two Singles using RXJava?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have this situation:

I'm using `MVVM`. I need to return a `Single<List<Items>>` but the list of items should be the merge of two lists (following the same order if possible).

Something like:

```
 fun getConfig(): Single<List<Item>> {
    return Single.just(localConfig.getConfig())
        .merge(Single.just(remoteConfig.getConfig()))
 }
```

Is that possible? Is Single the flow to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `zip` or `zipWith` and then a `+` operator to combine them

```
Single.just(localConfig.getConfig()).zipWith(Single.just(remoteConfig.getConfig()), BiFunction { list1, list2 -> list1 + list2 })
```

Comment: There are any "automatic" function to do this?

Comment: I know none of other ways :)